# Bind9 allow DNS rerouting?

Tags: server, dns, bind

I have a development server and I do not know exactly how to ask this. But when any of 4 computers type in [web.e.test] or something similar, Bind9 should then redirect you to that pc's IP address and render the site.

I have these configs set up. What am I missing with it?

**named.conf.default-zones**

```
    zone "dev.test" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/zones/dev.test";
    };
```

**named.conf.options**

```
    options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";
    
        forwarders {
            8.8.4.4;
            8.8.8.8;
        };
    
            dnssec-validation auto;
            listen-on { any; };
            listen-on-v6 { any; };
            allow-query { any; };
    };
```

***zones/dev.test***

````
$TTL 2d    ; default TTL for zone
$ORIGIN dev.test. ; base domain-name
```
$TTL 2d    ; default TTL for zone
$ORIGIN dev.test. ; base domain-name


@         IN      SOA   ns1.dev.test. deesrex@fox5.co.za (
                                0000002    ; serial number
                                12h        ; refresh
                                15m        ; update retry
                                3w         ; expiry
                                2h         ; minimum
                                )
ns1.dev.test.   IN  NS  127.0.0.1
ns1.dev.test.   IN      A       192.168.9.2

dev.test.   IN  A   192.168.9.2
*.dev.test.     IN      CNAME   dev.test.
*.j.test.       IN      A   192.168.9.10
*.e.test.   IN  A   192.168.9.20
*.b.test.   IN  A   192.168.9.30
*.h.test.   IN  A   192.168.9.40
````

Comment: Why not just edit the `/etc/hosts` file on the four machines rather than setting up a whole DNS server for it?

Comment: Multiple Sites = multiple hosts editing when you only need to properly set up the dns to create a new local domain for every site. Thats how I view it?

Comment: Sure, but do you control the DNS server the clients use?